# Loading a csv file which contains Latin characters with sql loader

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I have csv file which contains Latin characters like this : Østfold.

What should be my ctl file for this?

Comment: What is the encoding of your CSV-File?

Comment: iso-8859-1 @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: It got resolved by using "CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1" in CTL file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got resolved by using "CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1" in CTL file.